# Nested structs/Using a struct in another struct

Tags: c++, class, struct, nested

I've tried multiple things, and I keep getting the same error. First off, I want to say that I'm not working on anything Pokemon related, as my skills are obviously not good enough for that, this is just the most practical example I could think of to get the point across and make sense to others.

```
struct pokeDex {
            struct pokemonTemplate {
            std::string pokemonName;
            std::string pokemonMoves[3];
            int pokemonLevel;
            int baseATK;
            int baseDEF;
            int baseSPATK;
            int baseSPDEF;
            int baseSPEED;
            };

            pokemonTemplate Bulbasaur;
            Bulbasaur.pokemonName = "Bulbasaur";
            Bulbasaur.pokemonLevel = 5;
            Bulbasaur.baseATK = Bulbasaur.pokemonLevel * 10;
            Bulbasaur.baseDEF = Bulbasaur.pokemonLevel * 10;
            Bulbasaur.baseSPATK = Bulbasaur.pokemonLevel * 10;
            Bulbasaur.baseSPDEF = Bulbasaur.pokemonLevel * 10;
            Bulbasaur.baseSPEED = Bulbasaur.pokemonLevel * 10;

            pokemonTemplate Pikachu;
            Pikachu.pokemonName = "Pikachu";
            Pikachu.pokemonLevel = 5;
            Pikachu.baseATK = Pikachu.pokemonLevel * 7;
            Pikachu.baseDEF = Pikachu.pokemonLevel * 10;
            Pikachu.baseSPATK = Pikachu.pokemonLevel * 12;
            Pikachu.baseSPDEF = Pikachu.pokemonLevel * 6;
            Pikachu.baseSPEED = Pikachu.pokemonLevel * 15;
        };
```

I keep getting the error "Error: "Bulbasaur"/"Pikachu" does not name a type."
I've seen multiple questions about this, but none of them fixed it. I've tried having the structs separated, and just referring to the pokemonTemplate struct within the pokeDex struct, but that didn't work.

I've also tried making pokeDex a class instead of a struct, and I've tried having the pokemonTemplate struct outside of the class, and inside of the class, but I continue to get the error. Each time, I've been careful to define the pokemonTemplate struct before referencing to it, but I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize(in fact those are assignments here) the members inside a `class/struct` declaration.
Remove all the initializations which you're doing. Except that the nested `struct` should work fine.

Change the code to the following:

```
struct pokeDex 
{
    struct pokemonTemplate 
    {
      std::string pokemonName;
      std::string pokemonMoves[3];
      int pokemonLevel;
      int baseATK;
      int baseDEF;
      int baseSPATK;
      int baseSPDEF;
      int baseSPEED;
    };
    pokemonTemplate Bulbasaur;
    pokemonTemplate Pikachu;
};
```

And write your own `constructor` to initialize them or some setters methods to do the work.

Comment: Deleting everything except what you said, I'm now getting the following three errors:

error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
error: 'Bulbasaur' does not name a type
error: 'pokemonTemplate' does not name a type

Comment: I missed the semicolon`;` after the `struct pokemonTemplate` Will edit it.

Comment: @UchiaItachi Can you use the pokermonTemplate outside the pokeDex struct? I don't think so. Say I am right, what is the point of defining the struct inside another struct and not being able to use it anywhere else?